# Please help with a WiFi Driver Problem

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet

I have installed Ubuntu a few days ago because of I don't like Windows anymore because of it has a lot of bugs which makes things complicated. My idea is to use Linux more frequently but I am experiencing some issues. The most important thing I wish to fix is the WiFi because of the OS recognizes the device but after a few minutes it closes the connection and I have to reboot. My idea is that I have to install a different driver which is compatible with the device.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [update](http://askubuntu.com/posts/688344/edit) your question with `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A2` command output from a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t).

Answer (score 0):

When you say it closes the connection, does it actually disconnect from the network or do you just mean the internet stops working? I had an issue on an older machine (using Ubuntu 12.04) where it would remain connected, but the internet would not work.

For some reason Ubuntu was not playing well with my ISPs DNS servers, so I changed it to use the Google ones and that fixed the problem. (To change your DNS server click the WiFi icon at the top, click edit connections, select your network, and go to the ipv4 tab)

If the computer fully disconnects from the network (cant even ping the router), then you have a different problem. In which case, what WiFi card are you using, and have you tried checking for a proprietary driver? (Settings > software and updates > additional software)

Answer (score 0):

hola bueno se mantiene conectado al modem pero no conecta a internet tengo ubuntu 14 y la tarjeta de red es:

Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC

en los otros dispositivos puedo conectarme normalmente

Answer (score 0):

que puedo hacer para que no se me corte la conexion e intentado instalar los paquetes de driver pero me quedo estancado en la opcion "make" "make install" primero descargo el paquete despues lo descomprimo y luego me quedo pegado en "make" espero sus respuestas gracias